# Flask request Error werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, httprequest

Whenever I hit the post button on my /Accountwahl page I get this Error Message:

werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'forename'

in line:
user_forename = request.form["forename"]

This is a snippet of my app.py file(80% of it is just database creating, I'm pretty sure, theres nothing wrong with it):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash, sessions
import random
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate



app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "zWG3uzYMMrXp3TDYEZBgG4XAfYU4fd"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False


db1 = SQLAlchemy(app)


class users(db1.Model):
    user_id = db1.Column("UserID", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    forename = db1.Column("Vorname", db1.String(100))
    surname = db1.Column("Nachname", db1.String(100))
    email = db1.Column("E-mail", db1.String(100))
    password = db1.Column("password", db1.String(100))
    kind = db1.Column("Privat/Öffentlich",db1.String(10))

    def __init__(self, user_id, forename, surname, email, password, kind):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.forename = forename
        self.surname = surname
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.kind = kind




class row0(db1.Model):
    user_id0 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday0 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday0 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday0 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday0 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday0 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id0, Monday0, Tuesday0, Wednesday0, Thursday0, Friday0):
        self.username0 = user_id0
        self.Monday0 = Monday0
        self.Tuesday0 = Tuesday0
        self.Wednesday0 = Wednesday0
        self.Thursday0 = Thursday0
        self.Friday0 = Friday0



class row1(db1.Model):
    user_id1 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday1 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday1 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday1 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday1 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday1 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id1, Monday1, Tuesday1, Wednesday1, Thursday1, Friday1):
        self.username1 = user_id1
        self.Monday1 = Monday1
        self.Tuesday1 = Tuesday1
        self.Wednesday1 = Wednesday1
        self.Thursday1 = Thursday1
        self.Friday1 = Friday1


class row2(db1.Model):
    user_id2 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday2 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday2 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday2 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday2 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday2 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id2, Monday2, Tuesday2, Wednesday2, Thursday2, Friday2):
        self.user_id2 = user_id2
        self.Monday2 = Monday2
        self.Tuesday2 = Tuesday2
        self.Wednesday2 = Wednesday2
        self.Thursday2 = Thursday2
        self.Friday2 = Friday2


class row3(db1.Model):
    user_id3 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday3 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday3 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday3 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday3 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday3 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id3, Monday3, Tuesday3, Wednesday3, Thursday3, Friday3):
        self.user_id3 = user_id3
        self.Monday3 = Monday3
        self.Tuesday3 = Tuesday3
        self.Wednesday3 = Wednesday3
        self.Thursday3 = Thursday3
        self.Friday3 = Friday3



class row4(db1.Model):
    user_id4 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday4 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday4 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday4 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday4 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday4 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id4, Monday4, Tuesday4, Wednesday4, Thursday4, Friday4):
        self.user_id4 = user_id4
        self.Monday4 = Monday4
        self.Tuesday4 = Tuesday4
        self.Wednesday4 = Wednesday4
        self.Thursday4 = Thursday4
        self.Friday4 = Friday4


class row5(db1.Model):
    user_id5 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday5 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday5 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday5 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday5 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday5 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id5, Monday5, Tuesday5, Wednesday5, Thursday5, Friday5):
        self.user_id5 = user_id5
        self.Monday5 = Monday5
        self.Tuesday5 = Tuesday5
        self.Wednesday5 = Wednesday5
        self.Thursday5 = Thursday5
        self.Friday5 = Friday5



class row6(db1.Model):
    user_id6 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday6 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday6 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday6 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday6 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday6 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id6, Monday6, Tuesday6, Wednesday6, Thursday6, Friday6):
        self.user_id6 = user_id6
        self.Monday6 = Monday6
        self.Tuesday6 = Tuesday6
        self.Wednesday6 = Wednesday6
        self.Thursday6 = Thursday6
        self.Friday6 = Friday6



class row7(db1.Model):
    user_id7 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday7 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday7 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday7 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday7 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday7 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id7, Monday7, Tuesday7, Wednesday7, Thursday7, Friday7):
        self.user_id7 = user_id7
        self.Monday7 = Monday7
        self.Tuesday7 = Tuesday7
        self.Wednesday7 = Wednesday7
        self.Thursday7 = Thursday7
        self.Friday7 = Friday7




class row8(db1.Model):
    user_id8 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday8 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday8 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday8 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday8 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday8 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id8, Monday8, Tuesday8, Wednesday8, Thursday8, Friday8):
        self.user_id8 = user_id8
        self.Monday8 = Monday8
        self.Tuesday8 = Tuesday8
        self.Wednesday8 = Wednesday8
        self.Thursday8 = Thursday8
        self.Friday8 = Friday8


class row9(db1.Model):
    user_id9 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday9 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday9 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday9 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday9 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday9 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id9, Monday9, Tuesday9, Wednesday9, Thursday9, Friday9):
        self.user_id9 = user_id9
        self.Monday9 = Monday9
        self.Tuesday9 = Tuesday9
        self.Wednesday9 = Wednesday9
        self.Thursday9 = Thursday9
        self.Friday9 = Friday9

class row10(db1.Model):
    user_id10 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday10 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday10 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday10 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday10 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday10 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id10, Monday10, Tuesday10, Wednesday10, Thursday10, Friday10):
        self.user_id10 = user_id10
        self.Monday10 = Monday10
        self.Tuesday10 = Tuesday10
        self.Wednesday10 = Wednesday10
        self.Thursday10 = Thursday10
        self.Friday10 = Friday10


class row11(db1.Model):
    user_id11 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday11 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday11 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday11 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday11 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday11 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, user_id11, Monday11, Tuesday11, Wednesday11, Thursday11, Friday11):
        self.user_id11 = user_id11
        self.Monday11 = Monday11
        self.Tuesday11 = Tuesday11
        self.Wednesday11 = Wednesday11
        self.Thursday11 = Thursday11
        self.Friday11 = Friday11



@app.route("/Accountwahl", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def choose():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form["btn_identifier"] == "btn_identifier_public":
            session["kind"] = "public"
        if request.form["btn_identifier"] == "btn_identifier_private":
            session["kind"] = "private"
        return redirect(url_for("signup"))
    return render_template("choose.html")


@app.route("/signup", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def signup():
    signs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
    '7', '8', '9', '0']
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_forename = request.form["forename"]
        user_surname = request.form["surname"]
        user_email = request.form["email"]
        user_password = request.form["password"]
        found_user = users.query.filter_by(email = user_email).first()
        if found_user:                                   
            flash("Diese E-mail existiert bereits")
        else:
            usr = users("{{0}}{{1}}{{2}}{{3}}".format(signs[random.randint(0, len(signs))], signs[random.randint(0, len(signs))], signs[random.randint(0, len(signs))],
            signs[random.randint(0, len(signs))]), user_forename, user_surname, user_email, user_password, session["kind"])     
            db1.session.add(usr)
            db1.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for("login"))

    return render_template("sign.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    db1.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True, port=5002)
```

sign.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title%} Sign in! {% endblock %} 

{% block content %}  
    <form action="#" method="POST" class="inputs">
        <input type="text" name="forename">
        <input type="text" name="surname">
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <div>
        <label class="label1" for="forename">Vorname:</label>
        <label class="label2" for="surname">Nachname:</label>
        <label class="label3" for="email">E-Mail:</label>
        <label class="label4" for="password">Passwort:</label>
        </label>
    </div>
    <p>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for msg in messages %}
                <p>{{msg}}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    </p>

{% endblock %}
```

And my choose.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Accountwahl{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="/signup">
<div class="public">
    <input type="hidden" id="btn_identifier" value="btn_identifier_public">
    <input type="submit" name="public" value="Öffentliches Profil">
</div>
<div class="private">
    <input type="hidden" id="btn_identifier" value="btn_identifier_private">
    <input type="submit" name="private" value="Privates Profil">
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Have you tried `pprint()` on the `request.form` to check if you have any of the keys there? Usually you need to set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, like this `<form method="POST" action="/signup" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">`. On a side note, why are you declaring 11 classes when you should be resuing the class 11 times?

Comment: So I finally understood and solved this Error: Apparently, my signup function wasn't able to difference between the post when hitting the submit-button on the signup-page, and when you get redirected from the original page. Since this has other keys, etc., it raised the error. I fixed it now, by uniquely identifying the post. But to check the request.form with a print really helped, so thanks for that